# Django Duration Field convert to MM:SS:CC format?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following model called **Competition**. I am trying to store the records for each swimmer as `freestyle_50` as `mm:ss:cc` where **cc** refers to `centisecond` i.e 1/100 of second.

Is there anyway i can solve this problem using `duration field`? Also in Forms

```
class Competition(models.Model):

swimmer = models.ForeignKey(
    Swimmer,
    blank=True,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='swimmer_competition'

)
freestyle_50 = models.DurationField(
    blank=True,
    null=True,
)
freestyle_100 = models.DurationField(
    blank=True,
    null=True,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.timedelta` doesn't have option to store centiseconds, but you can store miliseconds which is centisecond multiplied by 10. Then if you want to read the swimmer result, you can simply round the miliseconds.